# How do I get my node to rotate even if my finger is outside the node?

Tags: xcode, swift, touchesmoved

Ill try to explain this the best way I can. I have this circle that I can rotate when my finger is moving on the circle. The problem Im having is that when Im rotating the circle and I move my finger outside the circle the rotation stops. I would like it to still have the touch even if my finger is outside the node. It works when Im in a single view controller but in spritekit I cant figure it out.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        if node.name == "circle" {

            let dy = circle.position.y - location.y
            let dx = circle.position.x - location.x
            let angle2 = atan2(dy, dx)
            circle.zRotation = angle2


           }
          }
         }
```

Comment: You've moved out of "circle" so `let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)` is not returning "circle" so `if node.name == "circle"` is false.

Comment: @beyowulf Yes but would you know how I could get this to work?

Comment: In a single view controller project I can use this code and it works but in spritekit the circle wont rotate:   `let touch = touches.first
if touch!.view == circle {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an optional SKNode to hold the current rotating node like `var rotatingNode:SKNode?`. You can override `touchesBegan`.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        if node.name == "circle" || node.name == "rightCircle" {

            self.rotatingNode = node


           }
          }
         }
```

From your comment it seems like you have other code in touchesMoved than what is posted in your question. But if you want to rotate either circle or rightCircle then say something like:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {




            let dy = self.rotatingNode?.position.y - location.y
            let dx = self.rotatingNode?.position.x - location.x
            let angle2 = atan2(dy, dx)
            self.rotatingNode?.zRotation = angle2



          }
         }
```

Then in touchesEnded:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.rotatingNode = nil
    }
```

Comment: `var isTouchInCircle = false` is that what you declared it as?

Comment: I have another circle and its moving both circles when I rotate one of the circles.

Comment: Did you name both "circle"? What is the instance variable of the other circle?

Comment: I updated my answer. As I said, it is difficult to say what the best solution is because I don't know what you're designing and it seems like you have other nodes than the one you put in your question. You should try to adapt my answer to your needs.

Comment: Im making two turntables.